# RTMP and JW player (offline stream picture)

Tags: nginx, jwplayer, rtmp

I have succesfully setup a RTMP stream using nginx and the nginx-rtmp-module.

playback in jwplayer is setup as follows

```htm
<script type='text/javascript'>
jwplayer('my-video').setup({
  file: 'rtmp://mystreamurl',       image: 'streampic.jpeg',
  width: '640',
  height: '360'
});
</script>
```

is there a way to have a picture/text showing stream offline when there is nothing on the stream?
there is 
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is use the JW Player's JavaScript API - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference

You can use the onError() event. You can pretty much put any arbitrary JavaScript you want in there, so one thing you can do, is replace the player with a picture when onError() is fired.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
will check it out 

thanks a lot.

Comment: No Problem, let me know if you have any other questions!